# win_get_url fails to get the file from the url to a remote windows server 2012 node

Tags: ansible

I need to copy a file from a jenkins server to a remote Windows server 2012 machine using win_get_url
My playbook looks as follows:

```
hosts: windows_ip tasks:
    name: Deploy to windows 
    win_get_url: 
      url: 'http://(jenkins_server_ip)/jenkins/view/Trunk/job/router/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/router/conf/router-service-context.xml' 
      dest: 'D:\router'
```

However it gives the following error:

fatal: [windows_ip]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Error downloading http://(jenkins_server_ip)/jenkins/view/Trunk/job/router/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/router/conf/router-service-context.xml to D:\router Exception calling \"DownloadFile\" with \"2\" argument(s): \"An exception occurred during a WebClient request.\""}

What is the issue over here?

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else that comes across this issue, the problem is that the underlying powershell script will not create the destination directory if it does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

I'd troubleshoot this by looking at the exact script. First. make sure ansible leaves it's script on the target node by running the following on the control node:

```
export ANSIBLE_KEEP_REMOTE_FILES=1
```

Re-run your playbook, and then log on to the windows box. Ansible's files will be in C:\users\\appdata\local\temp\ansiblexxxxx

Run/debug the script locally to figure out whats happening.